# Populate 2 columns of dataframe at the same time using apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code which is (simplified) like this. The actual data lists are tens of thousands in size, not just 3.

There is a dictionary of staff which I make a DataFrame from.
There is a list of dictionary objects which contain additional staff information.

Also:

1. The staff list and the extra staff information (master_info_list) overlap but each has items that are unique to them.
2. The "index" I am using (StaffNumber) is actually prefixed with "SN_" in the extra staff information, so I can't compare them directly.
3. The duplication of StaffNumber in the master_info_list is intended (that's just how I receive it!).

What I want to do is populate two new columns into the dataframe which get their data from the extra staff information. I can do this by making 2 separate calls to get_department_and_manager, one for Department and one for Manager. That works. But, it "feels" like I should be able to take 2 fields from the output of get_department_and_manager and populate the dataframe in one go, but I'm struggling to get the syntax right. What is the correct syntax (if possible)? Also, iterating through the list the way I do (with a for loop) seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

The examples I have seen all seem to create new columns from existing data in the dataframe, or they are simple examples where no mashing of data is required before comparing the two "lists" (or list and dictionary).

```
import pandas as pd


def get_department_and_manager(row, master_list):
    dept = 'bbb'
    manager = 'aaa'
    for i in master_list:
        if i['StaffNumber'] == 'SN_' + row['StaffNumber']:
            dept = i['data']['Department']
            manager = i['data']['Manager']
            break
    return [dept, manager]


staff = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Dave'],
         'StaffNumber': ['001', '002', '004']}

master_info_list = [{'StaffNumber': 'SN_001', 'data': {'StaffNumber': 'SN_001', 'Department': 'Sales', 'Manager': 'Luke' }},
      {'StaffNumber': 'SN_002', 'data': {'StaffNumber': 'SN_002', 'Department': 'Marketing', 'Manager': 'Mary' }},
      {'StaffNumber': 'SN_003', 'data': {'StaffNumber': 'SN_003', 'Department': 'IT', 'Manager': 'Neal' }}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=staff)
df[['Department']['Manager']] = df.apply(get_department_and_manager, axis='columns', args=[master_info_list])

print(df)
```

Comment: can you post your expected output from the given dataframe `pd.DataFrame(data=staff)`?

Comment: @dm2 - almost: it was enough to give me a clue as to where I was going wrong: ```df[['Department']['Manager']]``` should be ```df[['Department','Manager']]``` and I needed ```.apply(pd.Series)``` (whatever that does - I'll have to read about it) at the end. Then it worked. That said, after seeing @Andrej Kesley's answer below - that solves it in a different and more efficient way, I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `.merge`:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame([v["data"] for v in master_info_list])
x["StaffNumber"] = x["StaffNumber"].str.split("_").str[-1]
print(df.merge(x, on="StaffNumber", how="left"))
```

Prints:

```
    Name StaffNumber Department Manager
0  Alice         001      Sales    Luke
1    Bob         002  Marketing    Mary
2   Dave         004        NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Like it. Not strictly solving the OP, but solving the problem a different way, which is what I went with in the end. Thanks.